# Type of UTP cable for running outdoors

Tags: ethernet

Currently in our home we have UTP Cat5e cables for Internet connection, which have been here for over 10 years. We are now going to expand a line to the back of our yard and we'd like to make it a bit future proof. Ofcourse the Cat5e is still enough since it's gigabit, but nevertheless.

The distance of the cable should be about 60 meters. Also, it will run next to a pretty high power wire (for pump-machinery).

Now, what would be the best option? Just stick another Cat5e in there, or is a Cat6-type a better option?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you want UTP? S/FTP is a much better choice for long distances.

Comment: seconding @EEAA but if you're forced to run copper (for whatever reason) then use surge protectors (eg. PNET1GB from APC http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=pnet1gb&tab=features)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming fibre & S/FTP etc are out of the question financially...

Running 60m would really need cat 6, cat 5e would be pushing it by the time you added in patch cables at each end - but get it away from the AC power line, right away, if you ever want any signal to get through. 60m of 50/60Hz induction noise would be a signal-killer

If you want future-proof, then cat 6 (or even cat 6a) is good to 10GBASE-T if properly handled. Use solid cable, not stranded, watch out for how you bend it - keep large radiuses, & bury it in suitable conduit; don't fly it.

Comment: I would agree but say that you should look to see if you can stretch to S/FTP within your budget. Not quite the expense of fibre but provides a bit more shielding. And definitely use a plastic conduit end to end that is (if possible) sealed with the ends going into the property.

Comment: When used for 10/100/1000BASE-T, CAT6 has the same distance limitation as CAT5/5e.

Comment: but cat 5e doesn't have any overhead for 'future-proof', which the OP wanted. You don't want to bury a whole slew of cable this year, to discover next year that Belkin just made 10GBASE-T switches for 20 bucks & you don't have the cabling to support it